# How do i make shell script open different tabs raspberry pi

Tags: python, linux, shell, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a problem where i would like this snippet of code to run in a few different tabs on my raspberry pi

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Setup virtualenv
echo "Setting up virtualenv..."
eval "virtualenv ."
eval "source bin/activate"
echo "Virtualenv setup successfully."

# Start one
echo "Starting number 1..."
eval "python test.py -cf ./configs/config.json"
echo "Started number1"

# Start two
echo "Starting number 2..."
eval "python test.py -cf ./configs/config2.json"
echo "Started number 2"

# Start three
echo "Starting number 3..."
eval "python test.py -cf ./configs/config3.json"
echo "Started number 3"
```

So where each "Start one" "Start two" "Start three" i want each of those to run in different tabs or windows. I'm not sure if thats possible as i'm new to raspberry pi and linux.

How do i achieve this?